# Недоразумение с синтаксисом

Tags: javascript, node.js, парсер

Встретил в листинге кода одной книги незнакомый синтаксический момент при изучении node.js

```
var query = require("url").parse(req.url).query;
```

Понятно все, кроме `.query;`. Была догадка, что это один из методов модуля url, но в документации я не нашел его, да и скобок нет, что ещё больше отталкивает от догадки. Ещё думал, что это свой, особый синтаксис node.js и query в данном случае выступаешь неким параметром к parse, но ведь и он не идет в скобках, как "req.url", к примеру. В общем, объясните новичку, будьте добры, что может означать это странное query после точки без всяких скобок.

Comment: Всего лишь одно из полей объекта `require("url").parse(req.url)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы получите параметры строки запроса:

```
var url = require('url');
var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
var query = url_parts.query;
```

Это аналог `$_GET` в `PHP`.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все понял. Значит все-таки вид параметра такой.

Comment: @Alexander Если помог, нажмите галочку слева от ответа, спасибо.

Comment: @Alexander нет, это *НЕ* вид параметра

Answer (score 2):

Вызов `parse` возвращает объект, у которого имеется куча свойств.

`query` - это просто одно из них.

Вот полный список: https://www.npmjs.com/package/url#api